# Encoded GET request

Tags: http, get-request

I am a newbie, but I have not been able to determine if this request is malicious or not.  It has always came from a foreign IP address.  I have done multiple searches and have not found a way of decoding this.  Thanks for your help!

> GET
>   /?fp=QxBK9zIO8R%2BFqpUYXxBCsf/2d/VCb1UzUK/uJ1EMlO56LPORLsISePHmk%2Bh6iibCdtyls6EqlvlYNkjOtWf1xQ==&prvtof=4yrnquW2HYSkfIrzg%2BVYOgjMe3DUqpFReQ%2BpfOitLMw=&poru=ZcSu57I11wpvJIeprbkvODx9vwNZIIrWZSULp2Eu1j6rtx2flIgbe1T%2BHF4UJ7AqYgWE4MY9f%2B0Dck7AH1e45g==&
>   HTTP/1.1

Comment: Each URL param is base64-encoded. The decoded data is binary mostly, and I couldn't see anything immediately plain about it. What are the parameter names (fp, poru, etc.) -- do they mean anything to you?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some spam or scraper robot. The originator hopes that a previous attack has planted the file or code that will read those variables and send back whatever information it was looking for. It might use common fields that submit to posts and message boards.

Search for the `fp` `prtov` `poru` and you'll find many similar things.

ex: https://gist.github.com/superfeedr/806076

If you have no such page to receive the url and process it, then you can ignore the post. If it bothers you much, drop all packets from the originating ip with your firewall. Or do like this fellow making a mean reply to the one who posts such things:
[http://auracms.org](http://auracms.org/?fp=SWAt03is99wlsQVJKkSgOjubcHLJoBGpqvOchzGbtgP%2BklUX26O3oQQd1WAoLLASK3ClcBdalke2rpeXQydJXg%3D%3D&prvtof=ESHJKGYlkq4sTT4eIvXoXGlWYeglnu45bNXEexbTo70%3D&poru=J%2BAoWoLJReocCyPoMMXD6J8eVp8tVg0%2B6tATrD7xgQ0Xq2DdSzryoNn3z1UgZZsTZ9QXiWDCzyn5dmRGtUw3KLt4eq2CaSBaa8npui73ZIA%3D&)

Comment: Thank You for taking the time to look at this and I am not familiar with the parameter requests.  I will just ignore these in the future